# Distributions using nested loops

Tags: ruby

I would like to write a program which generates all distributions for a given `n`.

For example, if I enter `n` equal to 7, the returned result will be:

```
7 
6 1
5 2
5 1 1
4 3
4 2 1
4 1 1 1
3 3 1
3 2 2
3 2 1 1
3 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 1
2 2 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I wrote the following code:

```
def sum(a, n)
  for i in 1..a.length
    a.each do |a|
      z = a+i
      if z == n
        print i
        puts a
      end
    end
  end
end

def distribution(n)
  numbers_container = []
  for i in 1..n-1
    numbers_container<<i  
  end
  sum(numbers_container,n)
end

puts "Enter n"
n = gets.chomp.to_i
distribution(n)
```

I'm stuck in the part where the program needs to check the sum for more than two augends. I don't have an idea how can I write a second loop.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the help documentation for editing. You're doing it the hard way. Also, use more useful tags that describe the subject of your question, not the elements of the code you're using. `each`, `loops` and `for-loop` are basically worthless tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use recursion.

**Code**

```
def all_the_sums(n, mx=n, p=[])
  return [p] if n.zero?
  mx.downto(1).each_with_object([]) { |i,a|
    a.concat(all_the_sums(n-i, [n-i,i].min, p + [i])) }
end
```

**Example**

```
all_the_sums(7)
  #=> [[7],
  #    [6, 1],
  #    [5, 2], [5, 1, 1],
  #    [4, 3], [4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [3, 3, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

**Explanation**

The argument `mx` is to avoid the generation of permuations of results. For example, one sequence is `[4,2,1]`. There are six permutations of the elements of this array (e.g., `[4,1,2]`, `[2,4,1]` and so on), but we want just one.

Now consider the calculations performed by:

```
all_the_sums(3)
```

Each eight-space indentation below reflects a recursive call to the method.

We begin with

```
n = 3
mx = 3
p = []

return [[]] if 3.zero? #=> no return
# first value passed block by 3.downto(1)..
i = 3
a = []
# invoke all_the_sums(0, [0,3].min, []+[3]) 

        all_the_sums(0, 0, [3])
        return [[3]] if 0.zero? #=> return [[3]]
```

```
a.concat([[3]]) #=> [].concat([[3]]) => [[3]]
# second value passed block by 3.downto(1)..
i = 2
a = [[3]]
# invoke all_the_sums(1, [1,2].min, []+[2])  

        all_the_sums(1, 1, [2])
        return [[2]] if 1.zero? #=> do not return
        # first and only value passed block by 1.downto(1)..
        i = 1
        a = []
        # invoke all_the_sums(0, [0,1].min, [2]+[1])  

                all_the_sums(0, 0, [2,1])
                return [[2,1]] if 0.zero? #=> [[2,1]] returned

        a.concat([[2,1]]) #=> [].concat([[2,1]]) => [[2,1]]
        return a #=> [[2,1]]
```

```
a.concat([[2,1]]) #=> [[3]].concat([[2,1]]) => [[3],[2,1]]
# third and last value passed block by 3.downto(1)..
i = 1
a = [[3],[2,1]]
# invoke all_the_sums(2, [2,1].min, [1])  

         all_the_sums(2, 1, [1])
         return [] if 2.zero? #=> [] not returned
         # first and only value passed block by 1.downto(1)..
         i = 1
         a = []
         # invoke all_the_sums(1, [1,1].min, [1]+[1])  

                 all_the_sums(1, 1, [1,1])
                 return [1,1] if 1.zero? #=> [1,1] not returned
                 # first and only value passed block by 1.downto(1)..
                 i = 1
                 a = []
                 # invoke all_the_sums(0, [0,1].min, [1,1]+[1]])  

                         all_the_sums(0, 0, [1,1,1])
                         return [1,1,1] if 1.zero?
                           #=> return [1,1,1]

                 a.concat([[1,1,1]]) #=> [[1,1,1]]
                 return a #=> [[1,1,1]] 

         a.concat([[1,1,1]]) #=> [].concat([[1,1,1]]) => [[1,1,1]]
         return a #=> [[1,1,1]]
```

```
a.concat([[1,1,1]]) #=> [[3],[2,1]].concat([[1,1,1]])
return a #=> [[3],[2,1],[1,1,1]]
```

Comment: It seems that code is missing something, when I run it it returns nothing.

Comment: `p all_the_sums(7)` (or `puts`) to see what the method returns. If you run it within IRB or PRY (rather than from the command line), `p` is not needed to see what's returned.

Comment: If you have trouble following what I've done, I suggest you run through `all_the_sums(3)` with paper and pencil.

Comment: I'm getting lost in part `{ |i,a| a.concat(all_the_sums(n-i, [n-i,i].min, p + [i])) }`. I don't really get it how it does work there.

Comment: I provided an explanation (which I should have done previously). Even with the explanation, however, the reader may find it hard to follow if he/she is not experienced using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unary with `parameters` to have infinite amounts of parameters:

```
def test_method *parameters
  puts parameters
  puts parameters.class
end

test_method("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

So, `parameters` inside the block becomes an array of parameters. You can then easly loop through them:

```
parameters.each { |par| p par }
```

Also, don't use  `for` loops for this as they are less readable than using `each` methods.

```
[1..n-1].each do i
   # body omitted
 end
```

Comment: `for` isn't necessary less readable, and that's not why we don't use it. `each` doesn't leak local variables outside the block, but `for` does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you be able to work it out if you tried to call `sum` recursively. After this bit:

```
print i
puts a
```

Try calling `sum` again, like this:

```
sum((1..a).to_a, a)
```

It won't solve it, but it might lead you in the right direction.